# Tkinter with OOP python

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to get a very basic GUI with two tabs where the first one has the options of log in, register a new user and unregister this user. If i want to click to the second option (register the user or called "darse de alta") it should appear a second window (and closing the first one) where i can put my information to register (name, dni and phone number). Then the last point of this program should be adding this new user to a database called self.socios. This is because in the method "agregar" inside the class Registro_socios whenever i want to register a new user he has to be added to the database.
I don't know how to connect the new user with the class previously created.
Thanks to anyone who can explain and clarify in some way.

```
class Socio:
    
    def __init__(self,nombre_socio,dni,telefono):
        self.nombre = nombre_socio
        self.dni = dni
        self.telefono = telefono
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Nombre: {0}\nDNI: {1}\nTelefono: {2}".format(self.nombre,self.dni,self.telefono)

class Registro_socios: 
    
    def __init__(self,baseDatos_socios = None):
        if baseDatos_socios is None:
            baseDatos_socios = {} # Diccionario vacío con DNIs como Keys
            self.socios = baseDatos_socios
    
    def agregar(self,socio):
        if self.existe(socio): # En el caso que existe retorne True
            raise KeyError(f'{socio.__class__.__name__} ya existente') # A Python KeyError exception is what is raised when you try to access a key that isn't in a dictionary ( dict )
        self.socios[socio.dni] = socio
    
    def existe(self,socio):
        if socio.dni in self.socios:
            return True
        return False

root = tk.Tk()
miFrame = Frame(root) 
# miFrame = Frame(root,width=1000,height=500) 
miFrame.pack()

def alta_socio():
    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    miFrame2 = Frame(otra_ventana)
    miFrame2.pack()
    
    texto_nombreUsuario = Entry(miFrame2).grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    nombre_usuario = Label(miFrame2, text='Nombre de socio: ').grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_DNI = Entry(miFrame2).grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    nombre_usuario = Label(miFrame2, text='DNI: ').grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_nombreUsuario = Entry(miFrame2).grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    nombre_usuario = Label(miFrame2, text='Teléfono de contacto: ').grid(row=2,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    root.iconify() 

botonInicio = Button(root, text='Entrar',bg='orange')
botonInicio.pack()

boton_AltaSocio = Button(root, text='Darse de alta',bg='orange', command=alta_socio) 
boton_AltaSocio.pack()

boton_BajaSocio = Button(root, text='Darse de baja',bg='orange', command=baja_socio)
boton_BajaSocio.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For your Buttons at the bottom I see `command=function` and `command=baja_socio`, but I am not seeing any function called `function` or `baja_socio` defined, so I can't see how python would not stop there and complain unless you defined them outside of what you are showing.

Comment: wow, such a mistake i made, i correct it now. And the first problem of not appearing the second window has fixed.

Comment: Well I don't see a baja_socio function still. In the alto_socio function I am not sure exactly what your intent is but rather than making new Entry widget objects in a callback I would recommend having the Entry widgets already made when you start your application all packed into a frame. Then just have your callbacks pack and unpack the frames you want. I find this is easiest when your callbacks are methods and you store widgets as instance attributes that the methods can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many mistakes here. The first one is you call the mainwindow with `tk.Tk()` and the frames as `Frame`, so I imagine that you are importing tkinter twice like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
```

Forget the second import and put the `tk` before each widget.

Then the Button 'dar-se baja' calls a method that is not defined.

Inside the `alta_socio` method you are doing this:

```
texto_nombreUsuario = tk.Entry(miFrame2).grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

This is bad because while the `tk.Entry()` returns an instance of the class Entry, the `Entry.grid()` method does not return anything. so `texto_nombeUsuario` will be `None` and you will not to be able to access what is in the entry widget. You should do like this instead:

```
texto_nombreUsuario = tk.Entry(miFrame2)
texto_nombreUsuario.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Another option is to use a StringVar:

```
texto_nombreUsuario = tk.StringVar(root)
tk.Entry(miFrame2, textvariable=texto_nombreUsuario).grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

For the third Entry in `alta_socio()` you are using for the telephone the same variable you used for the name. Fix it. Finally you can add a `tk.Button` that will call a method which will create a `Socio`. Like:

```
tk.Button(miFrame2, text='Confirmar', command=add_socio).grid()
```

The method `add_socio()` can be a nested method from `alta_socio()` this way it will have access to the variables `texto_nombreUsuario`, `texto_DNI` and `texto_telefono`. It get the text from `texto_nombreUsuario` with the command `texto_nombreUsuario.get()` and call the previously created classes:

```
def alta_socio():
    def add_socio(): # this function is nested so it can access variables defined in alta_socio
        nombre = texto_nombreUsuario.get()
        tel = texto_telefono.get()
        dni = texto_dni.get()
        socio = Socio(nombre, dni, telefono) # here you call the Socio class previously defined

    otra_ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    miFrame2 = tk.Frame(otra_ventana)
    miFrame2.pack()
    
    texto_nombreUsuario = tk.StringVar(root) # this is a tkinter variable which contains the user name
    # this entry saves it values in the tkinter variable above:
    tk.Entry(miFrame2, textvariable=texto_nombreUsuario).grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    tk.Label(miFrame2, text='Nombre de socio: ').grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for all, but i still don't see the last point you made about the nested method. I have a method called "agregar", but is waiting for an argument socio to work with and socio have a phone number, dni and a name. So i'm kind of lost when you suggested to use the command get to just texto_nombreUsuario as it is not the unique thig that define the socio. If you could explain a lit more i would appreciate it in advance.

Comment: @AlexGarcia I added an example at the end of my answer so you can see how to make the nested function. The idea is that if you defined the new function inside the `alta_socio` it can access the local variables in it, so you don't need to pass the name, or the phone as argument of the function.